# Julia error: no method matching strange behavior

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia and the REPL answers seems strange to me:

When I run this *uncorrect* code :

```
mat = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

function minus(mat::Array{Int64,2}, min)::Array{UInt8,2}
    out = mat-min;
    # out = UInt8.(out);
    return out;
end

minmat = minus(mat);
```

I get this *correct* error message :

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching minus(::Array{Int64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  minus(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Any) at /home/hugo/dev/julia/test.jl:5
```

But when I run this *correct* (I guess) code :

```
mat = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

function minus(mat::Array{Int64,2}, min)::Array{UInt8,2}
    out = mat-min;
    # out = UInt8.(out);
    return out;
end

minmat = minus(mat, 1);
```

Julia gives me this <s>*incorrect*</s> error message :

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching -(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  -(::Complex{Bool}, ::Real) at complex.jl:298
  -(::Missing, ::Number) at missing.jl:93
  -(::Base.CoreLogging.LogLevel, ::Integer) at logging.jl:107
  ...
```

(notice the '-' in the function signature)

I see nothing related to this in the doc, so I am a bit confused, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to subtract a scalar from an array. You need to vectorize this operation with the dot operator.

```
function minus(mat::Array{Int64,2}, min)::Array{UInt8,2}
    out = mat .- min;
    # out = UInt8.(out);
    return out;
end
```

Now running this function yields:

```
julia> minmat = minus(mat, 1)
2×3 Array{UInt8,2}:
 0x00  0x01  0x02
 0x03  0x04  0x05
```

Note that your argument is an `Array` of `Int64` while you want the result to be `UInt8`. Your function call can easily end with an `InexactError` when the values will be out of bounds.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! It was not natural for me that operators are actually functions, that's why I had difficulties to understand the error message (and maybe also because I did this after a long day of work)

Comment: BTW, is my question stupid enough to delete it ? I do not think it will be useful to anybody else.

Comment: Do not delete the question! It will be useful because the broadcasting behavior changed between Julia 0.6 and Julia 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

The method error is not for your `minus` function, but is actually being generated by the line `out = mat-min`. Given `x::Matrix{Int}` and `y::Int`, Julia does not have a method for `x - y`. To see this, just paste the following in your REPL:

```
[1 2 ; 3 4] - 5
```

If the behaviour you desire is to subtract `min` from every element of `mat`, then what you really want to do is broadcast the `min` argument. That is, use:

```
out = mat .- min
```

Given this change, your function will now work as I suspect you intended.

Comment: Thanks also for the answer! I accepted the other one because of lower score. The reason I forgot to use the dot operator is because I use Matlab a lot at work and it does not require dot when subtracting a scalar to an array.

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux `I accepted the other one because of lower score` <-- Yes, that is the right thing to do in these situations, which are actually fairly common. Definitely do *not* delete the question. It is well set out and a perfectly legitimate question by StackOverflow standards. Typically, moderators will flag a question to be closed if it is not a good question by StackOverflow standards. Deleting is typically only used in cases where the question itself contains some sort of critical error.